# TortoiseSVN error: Working copy path does not exist in repository

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn, commit, working-copy

I've got a file that I tried to commit using TortoiseSVN, but it gave me the error that the working copy path does not exist, and I have to update my working copy first. So I tried a variety of things:

- Reverting the file to a previous version
- Deleting the file, trying to commit without it, then trying to re-add it
- Deleting the entire folder in my working directory and and re-updating it
- Doing a clean-up
- Resolving any conflicts
- Using the Repo browser to manually add the file to the repository, then trying to re-update, then re-deleting it through the Repo browser

And after all this, I still get the same error. I can't even do a fresh check-out because of the error:

**"Working copy path 'path/to/file' does not exist in repository."**

I'm completely out of ideas at this point. Help!

Comment: Could've at least explained the reason for the downvote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the directory to your SVN repository using TortoiseSVN. Then try to add the file.

Comment: Thanks. You mean re-adding the entire directory? Or just the problematic file? I already tried adding the file (I'll edit my question to make that clearer). I can't imagine removing and re-adding the entire directory will make a difference.

Comment: Directory path where problematic file is there.

Comment: Well, it worked. I deleted the entire directory from the repository using the Repo Browser. Then I did an SVN update on the parent directory. Then I resolved the tree conflict that appeared. Then re-copied the directory from my backup and re-committed it. A bit tedious, but finally things are working again!

Comment: It would be nice to have an explanation what happened. And how to avoid it in future.